# How can I create a check list items control in Symbian

Tags: symbian

How can I create a multiple check list items control as in the picture bellow using Symbian ?

I'm going to use this control in my SettingList view.

I'm using Carbide.C++ 2.7 , And Symbian S60 5th Ed SDK.

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the symbian lists API. Specifically you need the MultiSelection list box.

http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/Lists_API4.html#topic3.10

Comment: Many thanks Abhijith for your help, but i tried and failed when I used "listMultiQuery" generated by Carbide.c++ 2.7, Any farther help would be appreciated.